# RecyclerView repeating header after 11 rows

Tags: android, duplicates, android-recyclerview, repeat

I am working with really basic database which includes 2 parameters. I am using recyclerview to show data in my activity. Here is the problem. After certain number of rows (in this case 11) it just duplicates header and everything works correctly. I just want to get rid of that duplication and I need your help to do so. I'll try to add some pictures to show you what is going on

[image: first picture]

and here is duplication

[image: second picture]

and here is the code for recycler view

```
public class RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM.RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM> {
ArrayList<ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM(ArrayList<ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_workers,parent,false);
    RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM.RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM holder, int position) {

    ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV zamestnanci = arrayList.get(position);
    if (position == 0){
        holder.headerTopLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.headerBottomLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    holder.Name.setText(zamestnanci.getMeno());
    holder.Number.setText(zamestnanci.getCislo());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static  class RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView Name,Number;
    LinearLayout header;
    ImageView headerTopLine, headerBottomLine;
    RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        headerTopLine = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerTopLine);
        header = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
        headerBottomLine = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.headerBottomLine);
        Name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.workName);
        Number = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.workNumber);

    }
}
}
```

and XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerTopLine"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CELÉ MENO"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TELEFÓN"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerBottomLine"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Celé meno"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/workName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/workNumber"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:id="@+id/footer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I use it in my activity

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dbViewworkers);
                arrayList.clear();
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(workersActivity.this);


                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(workersActivity.this, 1, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {

                    ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV zamestnanci = new ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
                    arrayList.add(zamestnanci);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());




                workDb.close();

                adapter = new RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM(arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onBindViewHolder` is invalid, as it does not properly re-bind the view that was used in position 0 (leaves headers shown when it's re-used in different positions). Simple else case should fix your problem:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter_ZOZNAM.RecyclerViewHolder_ZOZNAM holder, int position) {

    ZOZNAM_ZAMESTNANCOV zamestnanci = arrayList.get(position);
    if (position == 0){
        holder.headerTopLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.headerBottomLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.headerTopLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.headerBottomLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.Name.setText(zamestnanci.getMeno());
    holder.Number.setText(zamestnanci.getCislo());
}
```

Comment: If you say that this is less violating piece of code I should use this instead of the previous answer... This works perfectly too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in Adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position
}
```

Comment: Nice ! ... This helped. You need to wait few minutes before I accept your answer.

Comment: This piece of code violates core of the design of `RecyclerView` (prevents view recycling) and should be avoided.